# ActiveRecord method last won't take parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to use the method `last` or even `take` in a controller like this

```
def news
    @posts = Post.last(2)
end
```

and when I go to the page I get the following error :

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

on the line

```
@posts = Post.last(2)
```

(and it does the same with `Post.take(2)`)

However, it works when I do this:

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 2)
```

but warns me about the fact that this method is deprecated.

Here's the code of my view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.text %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Ruby 2 and Rails 4

```
Person.last(3) # returns the last three objects fetched by SELECT * FROM people.
```

as stated here : 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last

edit:

Here's  the full controller and the full stacktrace : http://pastebin.com/1KKK8epm:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :news]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to posts_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def news
    #@posts = Post.order(:created_at).reverse_order.limit(2)
    @posts = Post.last(2)
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack-trace of the error please? to make sure its using the last method of ActiveRecord ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Here's the full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/WDY3vxKB

Comment: @Pacane I don't see this error on the stacktrace you've pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Post.order(:created_at).reverse_order.limit(2)
```

Comment: But it's written like that in the documentation, see my edit.

Comment: `Post.limit(2).all` please : .all returns an Array "undefined method `limit' for #<Array:0x0000000685a628>"

Comment: @Agis No I can't, it's from the ActiveRecord API documentation. :(

Comment: @Pacane I'm thinking that maybe you're overriding the `#last` method that ActiveRecord defines.

Comment: How am I overriding it? It's supposed to be there, ain't it ?

Comment: @Pacane yes, if you're using Rails 4 [it's supposed to work](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last), assumming you haven't declared a `last` method inside your model.

Comment: @Pascane can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: @Pacane `Post.last(2)` should work. Can you paste the whole controller file and the whole stacktrace? In your pasted stacktrace the error doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the answer above, if you always want it to be the last two entries created, or want to sort by any other method, you can do something like...

```
Post.order(:created_at).limit(2)
```

Comment: Grrr! `Post.all.class` returns an Array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation object that can be used for chain scoping!!

Comment: MrYoshiji - It works fine for me in a working app using this --  @products = Product.where("day_available = ?", @date_selected).order(:placement)

Comment: yeah but the method .all returns an array! and Array does not have the .order method neither the .limit method... If you want to use .all for chain-scoping, use `Post.scoped` to return an ActiveRecord::Relation object

Comment: @MrYoshiji this behavior is deprecated in Rails 4. Now, `all` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `scoped` method is deprecated. So you are basically wrong.